# How do I change file permissions on ElasticBeanstalk before docker image gets built?

Tags: wordpress, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am deploying a Docker image (Wordpress) on Elastic Beanstalk using a single container deployment.

My deployment zip file includes:

- `public` folder containing a complete wordpress build
- `Dockerfile`
- `.ebextensions/permissions.config`

The standard Wordpress image creates a volume `VOLUME /var/www/html` and in my Dockerfile I do

`COPY ./public /var/www/html`

Now the problem is that I cannot upload media using Wordpress admin dashboard.

`Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads/2019/02. Is its parent directory writable by the server?`

I've tried to change the permissions on the uploads folder using the EB config in `.ebextensions/permissions.config`

```
container_commands:
  91writable_dirs:
    command: | 
        chmod -R 777 /var/app/current/public/wp-content/uploads
    cwd: "/var/app/current"
```

I see from the logs that the docker image gets built before running `chmod`.  I've seen on other SO posts that some run the script on `/var/app/ondeck/`, but that fails with `the directory doesn't exist`

Despite all the above, my question is actually how do I get to upload media to Wordpress with my current setup.

EDIT: When I attach a shell to the docker container and change the file permissions of `wp-content/uploads` in the `VOLUME /var/www/html` I am able to upload media.  So how can this be made permanent on the VOLUME?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever wordpress docker image is built and run, the docker ENTRYPOINT of the wordpress image is executed first. Hence your command to change the directory permissions is not getting executed.

This ENTRYPOINT is a bash script located in `/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh`

If you want your command to be executed, you could add your command to this script and it will be called every time your container starts.

You could do it the following way -

- Start your container and copy the contents of the existing
  `docker-entrypoint.sh`
- Create a new `docker-entrypoint.sh` outside the container and edit
  that script to add your `chmod` command at appropriate location.
- In your `Dockerfile` add a line to copy this new entrypoint to the
  location `/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh`

Comment: I've added `chmod -R 775 /var/www/html/wp-content/uploads` to the end of the standard wordpress `docker-entrypoint.sh`, but it still doesn't change the file permissions.  When I check in the container after it has started it is still 755.

Comment: Do not add at the end. Add somewhere around the top. At the end won't work because the script defers execution to apache call and instructions at the end are not executed.

Comment: Thanks @Pranav, this crucial to my final solution. In the end I `chown www-data:www-data /var/www/html/wp-content/uploads` just before the `exec "$@"` line.  Everything is working as expected.